# How to report hacking mails to Gmail?

Tags: gmail, phishing

I get always mails with a subject "**CLAIMS**" or "**REPLY URGENTLY**" or "**CHECK YOUR MAIL**". I want to report this to Gmail, so that in the future I will not get such mails.

Currently, I am opening those mails and clicking "report as phishing". Though my reporting, I can see these mails always.

Please tell me what to do so that I can evade such hacking/phishing mails.

Answer (score 3):

I might be able to point you in the direction. We use Google Apps for business, and when suspicious emails gets out of hand, I do 2 things.

1. I follow this link to report [abuse](http://www.google.co.za/goodtoknow/online-safety/reporting-abuse/) > which takes me to the [phishing](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/184963?hl=en&ref_topic=3406179) section, instructing to do pretty much what you have done by marking mails as phishing, but also provides this [form](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/abuse) to report and submit the phishing activity.
2. Alternatively, I setup a filter rule targeting the sender's address / subject / content and either let it skip the inbox, be marked as spam, or let it be deleted completely.

Answer (score 2):

There is really nothing else you can do besides reporting them as spam or phishing. Eventually they will start skipping your inbox and go straight to the spam folder.

Comment: But they aren't skipping to spam folder.. to be frank those types of mails are increasing day by day. Anyway, I understand your point that we can't do anything further. thanks :)

Comment: Mark it also as spam then. After you’ve marked it as phishing.

Comment: ohh ok I will do that too.